# Blending white colors in images

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, alphablending, blending

I need to modify any image to get these results:

- White color has to be the color I specify, I don't want to keep source image's lightness.
- Rest of colors have to be tinted similar to Photoshop's "Color" layer blend mode. That is, I need them to look like if the source image was grey-scaled and then a color filter applied, even for non-greyscale images.

I am using the [UIImage + Colorize.swift](https://gist.github.com/lynfogeek/4b6ce0117fb0acdabe229f6d8759a139) functions. The `tint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage` function works as I need for non-white colors, but white color remains white. How could I get the results I need?

Comment: Belongs on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps superuser/ other stackexchange site. Not stackoverflow..

Comment: @RachelGallen I need an iOS-specific solution, this is not the correct place then?

Comment: consider apple.stackexchange.com There's also webapps.stackexchange.com which has an ios tag, but i think the apple one would be better

Comment: @RachelGallen If AppsDev wanted to know how to do this with PhotoShop I'd understand your objection. Being pretty new here myself and this being a question about UIImage/CGImage/Core Graphics, I'd like to know why Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: @thm it's not an objection, can I be clear about that, it just looked like it would get a better response on a specialised SE website.

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for clarifying, just wanted to know so I wouldn't ask questions on the wrong site.

Comment: @AppsDev Could you show two example pictures (original and desired result) of what you want to achieve?